# Understanding android gps and network detection for location

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/ as a reference and have the following code

```
GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(this);
if(gps.canGetLocation()) {
    // snip
} else {
    gps.showSettingsAlert();
}
```

I am running this on my phone via USB connection. On that device I have no wifi or mobile data connection.

However gps.canGetLocation returns true so I am not sure how that is the case.

My desired outcome is if the user does not have a wifi or mobile (3g,4g etc) connection then the showSettingsAlert should be called.

Edit: This code is from the article:

```
isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

When I Log this it is true, but if I have no data connection should it not be false?

Comment: Isn't GPS setting different from wifi & data settings?

Comment: in the GPSTracker canGetLocation will return false only if both network and gps is disabled..ie gps as well as wifi and mobile data has to be turned off

Comment: check the return value after you switch off gps too..

Comment: Setting enabled is different from "provider" available. You need to turn it off to get FALSE.

Comment: Ah okay. After I changed the Location GPS setting it worked as expected. Thank you.

Comment: You would need to add an answer, right now it is only a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the GPSTracker that you specified in your link `canGetLocation()` will return false only if both network and gps is disabled..

ie gps as well as wifi and mobile data has to be turned off